# django upload file with custom name and directory name

Tags: django

i want to setup my django models for upload file with custom path and filename, my curent models :

```
def update_filename(instance, filename):
    path = "accounts/"
    format = instance.id + "/" + filename
    return os.path.join(path, format)

class AccountsModel(models.Model):
    ChannelName  = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    AuthUri      = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    ClientSecret = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    ClientID     = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    ClientSecrets = models.FileField(upload_to="accounts/", default='', null=True, blank=False)
    RequestToken  = models.FileField(upload_to="accounts/", default='', null=True, blank=False)
    Note         = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=False)
    counter      = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    author       = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

when i try to upload file, i want to be like this :

```
/accounts/22/clientsecret.json
/accounts/22/token.json
```

my curent configuration return this error :

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: myupload_accountsmodel.ClientID
```

how i can do this ? Where i wrong ?

full project : https://github.com/scaltro/youtubeapp/blob/master/myupload/models.py

Comment: You set `ClientID` as **`unique=True`** and you tried to create an instance with same `ClientID`. That's the reason behind the exception

Comment: error fixed thanks @JerinPeterGeorge, but not save file how i want to do :(

Comment: What you mean by this, `/accounts/22/clientsecret.json` ?

Comment: 22 i want to be replaced with id of instance .. and fille need to have custom name, ClientSecrets = clientsecrets.json and RequestToken = token.json, how i can do this ?

Comment: In your model, there are two file fields. Which one's name should change?

Comment: for both models, i want file uploaded to be saved with custom name for specific field.

Comment: Your requirement isn't much clear to me.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge, when user upload file i want to ignore original filename and use custom name.  /accounts/{instance_id}/custom.json

Comment: What is **`.json`** here? file extension?